# Get HIGHEST and SECOND HIGHEST value for each item, break value ties with row's integer primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to use the following example from "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563974/get-highest-and-second-highest-value-for-each-id-sql" as the basis for my query - but don't know how to modify the example to meet my additional need of showing the primary key field in the results, and using the primary key field to break tied FilingDates.

**EXAMPLE DATA AND QUERY FROM EXISTING STACKOVERFLOW POST**
[Get HIGHEST and SECOND HIGHEST value for each ID (SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563974/get-highest-and-second-highest-value-for-each-id-sql)

TABLE Maintenance

```
equipment      Date 
    1        1/1/2019
    1        1/2/2019
    1        1/3/2019
    2        2/1/2019
    2        2/2/2019
    2        2/3/2019
```

What I need:

```
      QUERY LATESTDATES
 equipment     NewDate      PreviousDate 
    1         1/3/2019       1/2/2019  
    2         2/3/2019       2/2/2019
```

```
SELECT [a1].equipment, NewDate, Max([b].Date) as PreviousDate

FROM
(SELECT equipment,Max(Date) as NewDate
FROM Maintenance AS [A]
GROUP BY equipment) AS [a1]

INNER JOIN Maintenance AS [b]
ON [b].equipment= [a1].equipment AND [b].Date <> [a1].NewDate
GROUP BY [a1].equipment, [a1].NewDate
```

**MY DATA**
Table XYZQueue

```
FileNumber  FilingDate   PKID
  1          11/9/2023    1
  1          10/9/2023    2
  1          10/9/2023    3
  2          8/30/2023    4
  2          7/30/2023    5
  3          9/15/2023    6
  3          9/1/2023     7
  3          8/31/2023    8
  4          4/5/2023     9
  5          2/10/2023    10
  5          2/10/2023    11
  5          2/1/2023     12
```

**Desired Result:** Highest and second highest FilingDate per FileNumber, breaking duplicate FilingDate ties using highest PKID.

```
FileNumber  HighestFilingDate  HighestFilingDatePKID  SecondHighestFilingDate  SecondHighestFilingDatePKID
  1          11/9/2023                    1               10/9/2023                3
  2          8/30/2023                    4               7/30/2023                5
  3          9/15/2023                    7               9/1/2023                 7
  4          4/5/2023                     9
  5          2/20/2023                    11              2/1/2023                 12
```

Tried to modify SQL from an existing Stackoverflow article, don't know how to modify the SQL to meet my additional needs.

Comment: Seems like a [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) (read 'top 2") with a pivot.

Comment: I did try an alternate that uses partition. It seems to be slower though, and I couldn't figure out how to get highest and second highest result onto one line - ended up doing it as two separate queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really helpful to provide DDL and DML when asking questions. Consider:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (PKID INT IDENTITY, FileNumber INT, FilingDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @Table (FileNumber, FilingDate) VALUES
(1, '11/9/2023'), (1, '10/9/2023'), (1, '10/9/2023'), (2, '8/30/2023'), (2, '7/30/2023'),
(3, '9/15/2023'), (3, '9/1/2023'), (3, '8/31/2023'), (4, '4/5/2023'), (5, '2/10/2023'),
(5, '2/10/2023'), (5, '2/1/2023');
```

Using this, we can give each row a sorted ID per `FileNumber`, and then just return the 1s and 2s. Then a `CASE` expression can sort out which goes in which column:

```
SELECT FileNumber, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN FilingDate END) AS HighestFilingDate    , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN FilingDate END) AS SecondHighestFilingDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN PKID       END) AS HighestFilingDatePKID, MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN PKID       END) AS SecondHighestFilingDatePKID
  FROM (
        SELECT PKID, FilingDate, FileNumber, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FileNumber ORDER BY FilingDate DESC, PKID) AS rn
         FROM @Table
       ) a
 WHERE rn < 3
 GROUP BY FileNumber;
```

| FileNumber | HighestFilingDate | SecondHighestFilingDate | HighestFilingDatePKID | SecondHighestFilingDatePKID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-09 | 2023-10-09 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2023-07-30 | 2023-08-30 | 5 | 4 |
| 3 | 2023-08-31 | 2023-09-01 | 8 | 7 |
| 4 | 2023-04-05 |  | 9 |  |
| 5 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-10 | 12 | 10 |

Comment: Thanks very much! I appreciate the feedback/tips for posting questions - I'm quite new to doing that. I'll try this out.

Comment: I was able to run this query - thanks! Can you revise it so the HighestFilingDate is the most recent date, and the SecondHighestFilingDate is the next most recent. Currently they are reversed. --EDIT: I just changed "Order by [FilingDate] to DESC, and seems to have fixed the reversal - is that I'll I'd need to revise?

Comment: Hah, good catch. Yeah, I didn't include the `DESC` so the default `ASC` was used.

Comment: Don't you want `ROW_NUMBER` rather than `DENSE_RANK` if you want to break ties?

Comment: Ties are already broken by the PKID. Using a secondary column puts the tie breaker in the code.